# Test sandbox in-app purchase by id purchase live

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

My app already live in App Store. Now I want to update some feature into my app and test in-app purchase feature.

I login the sandbox user to test a purchase. But the error happened:

> Cannot connect to iTunes Store

So, what's wrong here? Can not buy the live purchase for sandbox user?

Answer (score 0):

Please read it 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2259/_index.html

You can't test live in app purchase by your sandbox account. you have below options
1. You can change in code make it for sandbox testing and do testing.
2. You can create a new apple id and do purchasing.
3. You can upload new version of the app with promo code and download it before release by promo code and do testing.

Note: If you use your sandbox account in live in app purchase testing than apple will invalidate that sandbox userid.